# Javascripts in dynamic loaded div not working (JSON)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, json

This might be duplicate - but in all other soloutions I can't seem to find any usefull information for my purpose.

I have this script parsing data to a .php file which generate content from a database query.

The .php file returns the generated HTML content as JSON - And this generated content includes som JS (some contextMenu functions to run when clicked on certain DIV's inside the loaded content).

These functions does not work in the loaded content.

From my main site I run:

```
$('.part_click').on('click', function(){
    var data_id = $(this).attr('id');
    $.ajax({
        url: 'explode_machine.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: {id: data_id, machineid: '<?php echo $machineid;?>'},
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data){
            $('#explode').html(data.html);
        }
    });
});
```

And the .php returns (among many things):

```
$('#clickedDiv').contextMenu('#menu-Div',{triggerOn:'contextmenu'});
```

`#clickedDiv` and `#menu-Div` is just fancy names used here as the actual names and numbers of id's may vary depending on the database query.

The .js file including the contextMenu function is loaded in the top of my main site.

If i right click on the `#clickedDiv` inside the dynamic loaded content nothing happens - If I add the same function to content outside the dynamic loaded content everything works as aspected.

As far as I understand from other topics the problem is either in the JSON parsing or in the  .html() - but I'm not able to sort it out.

Comment: An Element has to exist before it can have an Event attached to it.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the `#clickedDiv` element is added by your AJAX success handler, you need to initialise that plugin *after* the element is placed in the DOM. Try this:

```
$('.part_click').on('click', function(){
    var data_id = $(this).attr('id');
    $.ajax({
        url: 'explode_machine.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: {
            id: data_id, 
            machineid: '<?php echo $machineid;?>'
        },
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data){
            $('#explode').html(data.html);

            // initialise the plugin here:
            $('#clickedDiv').contextMenu('#menu-Div', {
                triggerOn: 'contextmenu'
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: `#clickedDiv` and `#menu-Div` are variable names generated by the .php file and the numbers of plugins may also vary so it's not enough to set the plugin static. But i'll try and tell if it activates the function just for testing purpose.